# What is the best way to generate a negative supply rail using a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

I need a ±5V symmetrical voltage to power 5 amps, 4 op amps and 1 in amp (TL081 and INA118). I would like to use only the 5V voltage of the microcontroller (an Arduino this case).

- Is it possible to use the 5V Arduino output to power the 5 amplifiers
  (symmetrically) and one more IC (with only 5V positive) that I will
  use?
- What is the best way to do this? (Generate a voltage of + 5V and -5V).
- I intend to power the Arduino with a 9V battery. Is that too little
  for an application similar to that?
- If I choose to use a single TL084, instead of 4x TL081. Would that
  make a difference?

If you can not do this, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common method for generating a negative supply rail for operation- and instrumentation- amplifiers (which don't require a lot of current) is with a capacitive charge pump.  A classic part for this is the [TC7660](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/TC7660).  The MAX232 can be re-purposed for this too, because it generates ±10V in order to transmit the true RS-232 levels.

There is also a way to get negative voltage from microntroller I/O and discrete components.
[image] ([source](http://www.edn.com/design/integrated-circuit-design/4368224/Voltage-inverter-employs-PWM))